# Remove current page from history browser without using location.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page `example1.aspx` that call another page `example2.aspx?id=5`.
In `example2.aspx` i take the id (5) and do an ajax request.
I don't like to show ?id=5, so i use

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

to remove `window.location.search`.
It works well, but my problem is that if the user click the back button, browser redirect to `example2.aspx?id=5`.
How can i remove the page `example2.aspx?id=5` from browser history?

I read a lot of answer for other question that suggest to use `location.replace` but it doesn't help me because
if i use `location.replace("example2.aspx")` the browser refresh the page and the page when refresh, if it doesn't have ?id automatically do
an ajax request with id=1.
**So, is it possible to remove a page from history without using `location.replace`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All what you want, [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) has:

```
  var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
  history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Comment: oh...it's so simple...i don't find that doc. Thanks